is the Ashtalakshmi concept recognized by vaishnavites?
The website of the Chennai Ashtalakshmi temple has a picture of Sri Tridandi Srimannarayana Ramanuja Chinna Jeeyar Swami and says the temple has his blessings.
https://ashtalakshmi.org/
Are the Ashtalakshmis manifestations of Lakshmi the goddess or are they simply 8 forms of wealth?
Wiki says
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashta_Lakshmi#:~:text=Ashta%20Lakshmi%20(Sanskrit%3A%20%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9F%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%80%2C,courage%2C%20progeny%2C%20and%20victory.

Ashta Lakshmi is now widely worshipped both by Sri Vaishnava and other Hindu communities in South India.[

